# Slider shows up on localhost but not on webserver

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have this weird problem with [this](http://leonblanco.in/cb/index.html) .html webpage. It has a jQuery slider which works on my PC and on wamp server too but doesn't show up when I upload it to the server. When I view the source, the code is the same as it is on the localhost. I looked all around but couldn't find anything.

Here is the CSS:

```
 .homepage_slider_section {
    width:100%;
    }

.homepage_slider_section .slider .flex-control-nav {
    display:none;
    }

.slides .slidecontents {
    z-index:2000;
    position:relative;
    }
```

I'm not sure what's going on here! :|

Comment: Are you sure you have included everything in your website?

Comment: +1 to @Chanckjh. you also have a few `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)`

Comment: @Chanckjh Yes. I'm quite sure I've uploaded everything. I zipped the folder and unzipped it directly on the server. So I don't think something is missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try moving this line:

```
jQuery('.slider').flexslider();
```

Into your document.ready() block.

Comment: Oh. Man! Thanks. You saved the day! :'D

Comment: My guess is that locally things loaded faster; remote server they loaded out of order, so by chance it worked locally, but when things loaded slower and/or different order on the server you were calling it before it was ready.